# Considering the work done from two different paths

Tags: vector-analysis, contour-integration

I am to consider two paths traveled below:

[image]

With the following vector field:

$$\vec F = \frac{-y \hat x + x\hat y}{x^2+y^2}$$

And I am to consider the work done going from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ with the circular and straight path. The work integral is:

$$\int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec r$$

The circular path I find is relatively straightforward (as this vector field looks a lot nicer in polar), however computing the line path is something I have difficulties with. My work integral looks like:

$$W = \int_{C} \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \int_{C} \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$$

Where $C_1$ and $C_2$ represent each line of the path for $y=x +1$ and $y=-x+1$.

For the $dx$ integral, I need to work out how $y$ depends on $x$ for each line. I've called for the parametrization $y=x+1$ and $y=x-1$ for the appropriate line.

$$ \int_{C} \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx = - \int_{-1}^0 \frac{x+1}{x^2 + (x+1)^2} + \int_0^1 \frac{-x+1}{x^2 + (-x+1)^2}$$

Apart from this looking quite hard to integrate, online calculators put each at$-\pi/4$. However, the $y$ integral is something that's causing me difficulty. It goes from $0$ to $1$ to $0$, so I'll need to split it up into two integrals, but what parametrization would I use? Would it be $y=x+1 \implies x = y -1$ for one integral and $y = x+1$ for the other? If so, how could I justify this other than a guess? If so, integrating this seemed to produce a messy answer that doesn't seem to look right, but that doesn't mean it's wrong. Is there a more efficient way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Along the path: 
$x+y = 1$

let $x = 1-t, y = t$

$x' = -1, y' = 1$

$\int_0^1 \frac {-y x' + x y'}{x^2 + y^2} \ dt \\
\int_0^1 \frac {1}{t^2 -2t + 1 + t^2} \ dt \\
\int_0^1 \frac {1}{2t^2 - 2t + 1} \ dt \\
\int_0^1 \frac {1}{2(t^2 - t + \frac 14) + \frac 12} \ dt \\
\int_0^1 \frac {1}{2(t - \frac 12)^2 + \frac 12} \ dt $

We need a substitution.

We might have avoided it had we chosen a different peramiterization at the beginning... oh well.

$t - \frac 12 =\frac {1}{2}\tan\theta\\
dt = \frac {1}{2}\sec^2\theta$

$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac {\pi}{4}}^{\frac {\pi}{4}} \frac {\sec^2\theta}{\frac 12 \sec^2\theta} \ d\theta \\
\int_{-\frac {\pi}{4}}^{\frac {\pi}{4}} \ d\theta \\
\frac {\pi}{2}$

And I suspect you will get the identical answer when we look at

$y-x = 1$

In hindsight, $F(x,y)$ is a conservative force.

$\nabla (\arctan \frac yx) = F(x,y)$

Which means that all path integrals with the same endpoints will be the same.

Comment: Even paths that enclose the origin?

Comment: I have reversed limits. For me, $F \cdot dr/dt = y/(x^2+y^2) + x/(x^2+y^2)$ and the limits for $x = 0$ and $x=1$ for $t$ if $x = 1-t$ should be $ x = 0 \implies t = 1$ and $x =1 \implies t = 0$ which gives me an answer of $-\pi/2$ for this.

Comment: @amd The path discussed here does not enclose the origin.  If you have a conservative field with a discontinuity, all paths that enclose the discontinuity will evaluate the same but they will not necessarily be 0.

Comment: @sangstar I see the error of my ways.  I thought we were traveling from (1,0) to (0,1) to (-1,0) in a counter-clockwise trip.  Counterclockwise is just so much more common in these sorts of problems.  That will indeed flip the sign.

Comment: But then it’s not the case the “all path integrals with the same endpoints will be the same.” That’s what I was too obliquely picking on.